# How to stop execution of the main module, if an exception occurs in a sub module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Have a situation here where I have a main module which calls in a number of sub modules, which in turn calls sub modules and its methods.

Eg:

Main module:

```
import submodule1
import submodule2

var1=submodule1.test(2,0)
var2=submodule2.verify(2,"zero")
```

Submodule1:

```
import blah

def test(x,y):
    try:
       return x/y
    except:
       #some code to print the error to log file
       #some code to determine if this is a critical error
```

submodule2:

```
import blah

def verify(x,y):
    try:
       return x*y
    except:
       #some code to print the error to log file
       #some code to determine if this is a critical error
```

Now, in the above case, the first call to method "submodule1.test(2,0)" will throw an exception which is logged into a log file and then I try determine if the error is a critical one or not. If it is a critical error, I want to stop execution and close all files, conenctions, modules etc (basically cleanup).

With the above code the control returns to the main module, the execution proceeds to the next line.

My main module might have number of methods or object instantiations. I do not want to check for a condition for every single statement.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved? Thank you!

Comment: If it's a critical error, just kill it using one of the many available ways, like `sys.exit(-1)`.

Comment: Or just `raise` the error if critical and let it bubble up. You can have a `catch` in the outermost call that does what it should (like exit or reboot or whatever else)

Comment: sys.exit() might not close all files that I have open (like the log files or the input sheet) also any selenium connections that I have established might not be closed as well right?

Comment: @ArunPadmanabhan: `sys.exit()` will terminate the process, and when that happens, all files and connections will be closed by the operating system.  (Actually, it will raise a `SystemExit` exception, which you can catch, and which will cause any files in `with` blocks to be closed, any `finally` code to execute, etc.  But you don't need to close files if the process is ending anyway, unless you care about the contents of your buffers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best way here would be to just let the exception propagate up to the main module.

```
try:
    # Code
except:
    # Print
    if is_critical():
        raise  # This will re-raise the exception you just caught.
```